# Detect rapid increase in time series

Tags: time-series, anomaly-detection

I have a short time series of daily counts ( 6 days = 6 counts : 12, 15, 69, 35, 97, 107). This looks like a rapid increase from its initial count of 12.

What are some of the statistical techniques to detect such large increases in short time period?

"rapid increases" and "short time period" are rather loose terms, but, I am looking for techniques where these can be 'parameters' that I can provide.  For example, "short period" could be 5 days. 'Rapid increase' could be 20% increase day-to-day or 90% increase in 5 days...something like that.

Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I suppose you also want to detect rapid _decreases_? If so, this is an _anomaly detection_ problem: you want to detect when the response significantly differs from its forecasted value. You're on well-trodden ground, so you'll find lots of questions here, libraries on github, and a rich scientific literature on the subject. Welcome to the site and good luck.

Comment: Are you looking to cluster data based on rapid increases/decreases?

Comment: @Gingerbread No, I am not looking to cluster data based on rapid increases or decreases.

Comment: @Emre For now, rapid increases is what I want. I have done anomaly detection in the past (on time series). There are issues with too little data (say 5 - 10 data points). Some techniques work well only if the number of observations exceed 2 * # of periods. For very little data, such as mine, the only option I see is to do some kind of vector-anomaly-detection (ignore time aspect totally) and do some custom heuristics on what is expected.